# github actions error - getting error in google-github-actions/setup-gcloud@v0

Tags: google-cloud-platform, github-actions, gcloud

In github actions on using  `google-github-actions/setup-gcloud@v0`
during the workflow process, its throwing the error

```
Error: google-github-actions/setup-gcloud failed with: error parsing credentials: Unexpected token � in JSON at position 0
Ensure your credentials are base64 encoded or validate JSON format: 
    {
      "type": "service_account",
      "project_id": "project-id",
      "private_key_id": "key-id",
      "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nprivate-key\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
      "client_email": "service-account-email",
      "client_id": "client-id",
      "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
      "token_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
      "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
      "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/service-account-email"
    }
```

Comment: How are you specifying the JSON? The error looks like an encoding issue such as Unicode Byte Markers at the beginning of the file. Edit your question with the missing details.

Comment: actually I am just using this action `google-github-actions/setup-gcloud@v0` , I haven't built it, the error is been thrown on that action

Comment: Per @john-hanley's comment, errors alone aren't particularly useful. Please include a minimal repro of your GitHub Actions workflow (YAML). You cannot run `google-github-actions/setup-gcloud` alone, you need to authorize it using `google-github-actions/auth` See [Authorization](https://github.com/google-github-actions/setup-gcloud#authorization). Using Service Account keys is deprecated though this may be the default behavior if you haven't referenced a key.